# Merging multiple paths into one D3(SVG)

Tags: svg, d3.js, path, merge

Could someone explain me how to merge multiple paths from a group into one single path.All paths are absolute (capital letters).

```
pathGroup.append("path")
.attr("d", "M25, 60 C100, 0 25, -10 25, 15 C25, -10 - 50, 0 25, 60 Z")

pathGroup.append("path")
.attr("d", "M55, 60 C100, 0 15, -10 25, 45 C25, -10 - 50, 0 100, 60 Z")

 pathGroup.append("path")
.attr("d", "M100, 60 C44, 0 15, -10 25, 45 C25, -10 - 50, 0 100, 60 Z")

 //pathGroup.each create a single path ?
```

Is it possible to iterate through the  element with an .each statement and sum all of them ?
I have set a fiddle to show my question.
http://jsfiddle.net/5Td4Q/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can just concatenate the path strings with absolute coordinates:

```
var combinedD = "";
pathGroup.selectAll("path")
  .each(function() { combinedD += d3.select(this).attr("d"); });
parent.append("path")
  .attr("d", combinedD);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Td4Q/4/). I've also fixed the errors in your paths (space between minus sign and number).

Comment: Hello, first thank you for the answer concatenating would work.I am however trying to combine around 50 000 paths into one, and this would not be a possible solution for me.Is there any other way to "sum" paths.I am not even sure if that is mathematically possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be a possible solution for you? Note that there's no math involved in concatenating paths.

Comment: I received Error: Problem parsing and i assumed that the path "string" i generate is just to long.It is however possible that i have some punctuation problem inside the path.Could i also ask you if there would be any difference in performance having 50 000 separate paths and having a single concatenated one ?

Comment: I can't really help you without an example of what's going wrong. In general, it should be faster to have a single path.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but would this also be possible if the paths had each their own transform-value? Say I have an array of 1300 plots on a graph, each their own path with a transform value - can I combine their path and transform values, and maybe merge them with another path?

Comment: You can't do it in this way; it would be more difficult because you'd have to account for the translations.