# How to merge paths with translate() values to a single one (D3 / SVG)?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a number of paths that I want to join to get a single path. However, for each path a `translate()` was applied. I found **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914504/merging-multiple-paths-into-one-d3svg)** that discusses the merging of paths (you may use [the sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5Td4Q/4/) they use there to answer my question), but this cannot be applied for cases where a path is translated.

How can I manipulate the `d` attribute so that the `translate()` value is taken into account and I can merge the paths successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the `d` value so that you don't need to translate anymore.  Suppose you have this path:

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
<path transform="translate(50,20)" d="M25, 60 C100, 0 25, -10 25, 15 C25, -10 -50, 0 25, 60 Z" />
</svg>
```

In this case you need to first change the commands to lowercase commands (relative).

```
 d="M25,60c75,-60,0,-70,0,-45c0,-25,-75,-15,0,45z"
```

You can do it by using this tool:[Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv)

In order to incorporate the translation you change the value for the first command M by adding the translation ( translate(50,20) ): d="**M75,80**c75,-60,0,-70,0,-45c0,-25,-75,-15,0,45z"

25+50 = 75; 60+20 = 80

And this is the resulting path where you don't need to translate anymore:

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
<path d="M75, 80 C100, 0 25, -10 25, 15 C25, -10 -50, 0 25, 60 Z" />
</svg>
```

Now you should be able to apply the method explained in this answer: [Merging multiple paths into one D3(SVG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914504/merging-multiple-paths-into-one-d3svg)